# Interpreting Seidel Aberration coefficients

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I am trying to model a simple system in Zemax (**though I think the question is general and is not limited to Zemax app**), but the ray-tracing does not seem to be consistent with the analysis of the system in terms of Seidel aberration values. Here's the system layout:

[image]

When the system contains only the Eye model and the OL lens, it can be referred from the Seidel diagram that the SUM of the aberrations at IM1 for field curvature and distortion are +9um and -19um respectively. It can seen that the peripheral rays' focus is lagging the paraxial focus - thus, the image is not flat:

[image]

Then, when I add the achromatic pairs P1 and P2, the new image is at surface Im2, the new SUM of Seidel coefficients for filed curvature and distortion are +13 and -20 respectively:

[image]

Thus, I would expect the IM2 surface to be even more curved, however, looking at the IM2 plane ray diagram, the peripheral points seem to focus much closer to the paraxial image plane - thus, the field curvature seems to be much smaller. So, the question is why the Seidel coefficients for filed curvature for IM2 are larger than for IM1, but the apparent ray-tracing shows smaller filed curvature in IM2 (which is expected to be larger than in IM1)?